# Eclipse "paste" command broken

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on OS X 10.8.2 and Eclipse Juno; Copy/Paste/Cut suddenly broke. No response inside Eclipse.

Maybe a rogue plug-in (?) but that doesn't matter, can I just reset the values?

Which combination should I bind to <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+{C,V,X}?

- Paste from the clipboard in "Editing Text"
- Paste from the clipboard in "Dialogs and Windows"
- Paste from the clipboard in "Windows"
- Other?

If you know how to do this in a preferences file, even better, I use `keyConfigurationId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"` but I don't know how to choose these parameters for the `keyBinding` rule in
`org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.commands`:

- contextId
- commandId

Comment: Hmm... it's not a good time for me to be changing anything major in my setup... I rely on it too much and the consequences of introducing more problems are scary... or did you mean that this is "a known issue" and will be fixed by upgrading?

Comment: It seems like the "rogue" plug-in was from Google! Wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my installation, those commands are set to in "Dialogs and Windows". You should be able to also get that automatically by hitting the "Restore Command" button after selecting one of those commands. Or in very hard cases, use "Restore Defaults" in the bottom right corner to recreate all key bindings.

If you use the Android Development tools, please upgrade to the latest version, as a [copy-paste-issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34630) was fixed in ADT 20.0.2, which occurred for many Eclipse Juno users.

That all said, you really should upgrade to SR1, as that is a bugfix release, no feature release. So chances are very high it fixes more problems than it introduces.

Comment: Copy-paste from Android is exactly what was happening! I am accepting your answer, thanks! BTW do you have a link to step-by-step upgrade instructions for SR1?

Comment: Just run Help -> Search for Updates. Eclipse Juno comes with a pre-configured update site for Juno, and the SR1 release replaced the normal Juno release on that update site.

Comment: Ah, cool. Vielen Dank. I am on v4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800, maybe I already have that?

Comment: Yes, the 4.2 is Juno, .1 is SR1.